# Admin Quick Edit PRO for Opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Есть Opencart 3, нашел в интернете модуль без опознавательных знаков, не написано с какой версией совместим. Написано версия 5.7.1. Установил, нормально установилось, но при нажатии кнопки редактирования модуля выходят ошибки:

```
> Notice: Undefined index: token in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php
> on line 619Notice: Undefined index: token in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php
> on line 625Notice: Undefined index: token in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php
> on line 631Notice: Undefined index: token in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php
> on line 635Notice: Undefined index: token in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php
> on line 636Notice: Undefined index: token in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php
> on line 637Notice: Undefined index: token in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php
> on line 638Notice: Undefined index: token in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php
> on line 639 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
> 'Error: Could not load model extension/event!' in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\system\engine\loader.php:89
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php(920):
> Loader->model('extension/event') #1
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\admin\controller\extension\module\admin_quick_edit.php(644):
> ControllerExtensionModuleAdminQuickEdit->updateEventHooks() #2
> [internal function]: ControllerExtensionModuleAdminQuickEdit->index()
> #3 C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\system\engine\action.php(79):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\admin\controller\startup\router.php(26):
> Action->execute(Object(Registry), Array) #5 [internal function]:
> ControllerStartupRouter->index() #6
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\system\engine\action.php(79):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #7 C:\OSP in
> C:\OSPanel\domains\opencart\system\storage\modification\system\engine\loader.php
> on line 89
```

не к той версии модуль?

Comment: Этот модуль и на 2 версию бывает не ложится. Часто глючит этот модуль. Скорее всего баг.

Answer (score 0):

В opencart 3 переменная `token` заменена на `user_token` - значит этот модуль от Opencart 2.